# How to use (- Hyphen) in a variable name in shell?

Tags: shell

I am planning to use(hyphen -) in a variable `test-ing=3.0` but I am unable to print value `$test-ing`. I know hyphen will not work on shell, any possible way to print the variable value without changing the variable name?

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea. (Why don't you throw in a backslash and a dollar sign for good measure ;-) ?) The older one gets the more important appears to become portability.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Agreed. Let's have a car analogy: _How to use custard (pudding) instead of lugnuts?_ I have to wonder what's driving the decision not to change the variable name ... [sunk cost fallacy](https://time.com/5347133/sunk-cost-fallacy-decisions/), p'raps?

Comment: Save yourself tons of troubles and use underscores instead, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming an environment variable, since `test-ing` is not a valid shell variable name, you can use `printenv`:

```
% env foo-bar=baz printenv foo-bar
baz
```

Or Perl:

```
% env foo-bar=baz perl -e 'print $ENV{"foo-bar"}'
baz
```

Or other tools like Python, etc.

Comment: `ENVIRON` array in `awk` also

Comment: Beware though that some shells like `mksh` remove from the environment the variables that can't be mapped to shell variables (try  `env foo-bar=baz mksh -c 'printenv foo-bar'` for instance). So use at your own risk and be prepared for those not to *traverse* all `exec()` chains.

Answer (score 6):

In the [`rc` shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc) or derivatives (`es`, `akanga`), just about anything can be used in a variable name.

All variables are also exported to the environment.

However, in Byron Rakitzis' clone of `rc` for Unix (from which `es`/`akanga` derive), as opposed to the *port* of plan9 `rc` (now publicly available since plan9 has been released as FLOSS), note that for those that contain characters outside of `a-zA-Z0-9_` or sequences of two or more underscores, an encoding/decoding is used upon export/import from the environment:

```
$ rc
; foo-bar = baz
; echo $'foo-bar'
baz
; printenv foo-bar
; env | grep foo
foo__2dbar=baz
```

In Byron's `rc`, one also can't use a variable with an empty name:

```
; '' = 1
rc: zero-length variable name
```

Things like `1 = foo` or  `* = (foo bar)` work, but they set the positional parameters, not variables.